# Setting up sftp on multiple ports in my centos machine

Tags: ssh, centos, port-forwarding, sftp, centos-7

I have a **Centos** machine version `centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64`. I am trying to change the sftp port, which is currently the **default** port **22**. I was able to follow the article https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-separate-port-for-ssh-and-sftp-on-centos-rhel/ and was able to set **sftp to port 22 and ssh to port 2222**. I have existing users using the machine and this change will affect them. I `am trying to set sftp on both 22 and 2222 port and keep ssh on port 22`. Is it possible to do that by any means. I have searched online but could not find much help regarding that.

In my **sshd_config** I updated the following:

```
Port 22
#2222 added as extra argument to change sftp port
Port 2222

# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
#custom value to change sftp port
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

#extra arguments for port change
Match LocalPort 22
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

In my **sshd_config** file, if I just add the following:

```
Port 22
#2222 added as extra argument to change sftp port
Port 2222
```

and none of the other changes above, I am able to connect ssh on two ports, but sftp only on 22. I am looking for exactly the other way, SSH on 22 and sftp on both 22 and 2222

Comment: What happens when you try to connect to port 2222 with an SFTP client? What SFTP client are you using? Do you get an error message? What does the message say?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The simple `Match` condition of a port you should only use for the 2222 port - it's the one, where you want sftp *only*.

In the other rule, you need to specify not only port (this would kick out your regular users too), but *also* another condition (if there are some users or groups which are not to be allowed to use other possibilities besides the sftp).

As a man page clearly states: "If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the file."